# jQuery modal displays random info every time the 'see more' button gets pressed

Tags: jquery, append

I'm getting data from an API, I was able to display on the browser as an individual tile (image, names, phone number, ...). I have a jQuery modal in it so when press: "get more info", it'll popup a window. This is where my problem starts: Let's say I get 4 tiles, and if I want to get more info from tile 2, the modal will popup and it'll give me the info from tile 1. If I press another tile, I'll get info from tile 2, and so on. How can I make sure that when I want to get info from an specific tile, i'll get the right info when the popup modal comes up?

```
for(var i=1; i<data.length; i++) {
            var showBusiness = data[i].zipcode
            var showName = data[i].name
            var showNumber = data[i].number
            var showAddress = data[i].address
            var showImage = data[i].image
            var showWebsite = data[i].website
            var showCategory = data[i].category
            var showHours = data[i].hours
            var showSummary = data[i].summary
            var showId = data[i].id

  if( zipCodeProvided == showBusiness ) {                                                                   
      $("#header").append(     
        `<div class='theDiv' id='theDiv'>
            <img class="picture" src=${showImage} alt="picture"/>
            <h1 id='name'>${showName}</h1>
            <h2 id='address'>${showAddress}</h2>
            <h2 id='number'>${showNumber}</h2>
            <div id="ex1" class="modal">
              <img class="picture" src=${showImage} alt="picture"/>
              <h1 class='name'>${showName}</h1>
              <h2 class='address'>${showAddress}</h2>
              <h2 class='number'>${showNumber}</h2>
              <h2 id='hours'>${showHours}</h2>
              <h2 id='website'><a href='${showWebsite}'target="_top _blank"><i class="fas fa-globe"> website</i></a></h2>
              <h2 id='category'>Category: ${showCategory}</h2><br/>
              <h2 id='summary'>${showSummary}</h2>
              <a class='modal-info2'href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a>
            </div>
            <p><a class='modal-info'href="#ex1" rel="modal:open"> ...more info</a></p>            
        </div>`)
      }  
    }
  }
```

Comment: here it is on codepen https://codepen.io/eddycaldas/pen/oPPzgv use zip code 80015

Comment: I figured it out. I added a unique ID to each modal. D